# How to run second display off internal gpu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time after years of windows usage. In my windows setup I used to have my graphics card powering my main screen and the iGPU power the secondary one. I don't have the slightest idea about getting the same setup in Ubuntu since it won't recognize my second screen. How do I get a second screen powered by iGPU?

Here's a picture of how everything looks after I finished nvidia driver installation

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: I found [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/821031/616451) that might or might not work for you.