# Ubuntu freezes sometimes and USB ports stop working

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, usb, multiple-monitors

I've been experiencing a problem in Ubuntu lately which is making work quite frustrating: my system will totally freeze and the only solution I've found is to do a hard reboot. For reference, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Ubuntu Gnome).

The strange part is that the USB ports also stop working. For example, the caps lock key doesn't toggle the caps lock light and inserting a flash drive doesn't turn on its light either. So when it freezes, the keyboard is completely unusable. Another thing is that if music happened to be playing at the time, it gets stuck on a loop on the last little sound byte. Otherwise, the monitors are all on and there is no excessive sound from the hard drive.

I suspect a graphics issue but I don't know for sure. On the graphics side, I have three monitors running using [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593938/how-to-run-both-intel-and-nvidia-graphics-card-driver-on-dual-monitor-setup/821031#821031) which might be creating issues. That said, some of my coworkers are doing similar things without error. It could be a hardware issue too. I ran memtest to check the RAM but that completed without error on all the tests.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information. The error isn't really reproducible in any way I can see though.

Answer (score 0):

I started recently to have the same issue, also I'm using ubuntu gnome 16.04. I think it's probably linked to usb/network.
I have created a bug ticket here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1727254

You can add your own description there and indicate that the bug affect you.

Comment: I looked at the ticket. My problem isn't as predictable and I don't have tlp packages installed so I don't think it's the same. Thanks though