# Use Intel built-in graphics for monitors while still running NVidia drivers for GPUs

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have an NVidia graphics card in my PC with an HDMI port and the motherboard also comes with Intel graphics and has a built-in HDMI port for that.

When I boot my PC it goes to the NVidia card.  If I plug a monitor into the Intel HDMI port, I don't see any signal.

Is it possible to configure Ubuntu so it boots with monitors using Intel built-in graphics but still leaves NVidia drivers running GPU?

I'm asking because I use GPU mostly for deep learning, and I want to keep GPU DRAM for GPU.

Answer (score 0):

This question duplicates several much older questions.  Just posting so anybody looking at this can more easily refer back to the old answers.  In short, it's doable but somewhat complicated:

- 2018: [Intel for display, NVIDIA for computing](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/bc7b9f424e3d5deb0c0b8bba990b1bc5)
- 2018: [How to configure iGPU for xserver and nvidia GPU for CUDA work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061551/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-work)
- 2018: [Use integrated graphics for display and NVIDIA GPU for CUDA on Ubuntu 14.04](https://gist.github.com/alexlee-gk/76a409f62a53883971a18a11af93241b)
- 2017: [How to run both Intel and Nvidia graphics card driver on dual monitor setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593938/how-to-run-both-intel-and-nvidia-graphics-card-driver-on-dual-monitor-setup)
- 2016: [How to configure igpu for xserver and nvidia gpu for cuda?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779530/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda)